# robocopy and source folder name/encoding

Tags: robocopy

On windows 8 I am trying to copy a folder using robocopy

```
robocopy /MIR /E /DCOPY:T /s "c:\test\xupdate can’t be deployed" "c:\test\out\"
```

But it fails with:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 9. april 2015 10:56:35
   Source : C:\test\xupdate canÈÃÍt be deployed
     Dest : C:\test\out\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /DCOPY:T /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

2015/04/09 10:59:44 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory C:\test\xupdate canÈÃÍt be deployed

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So the problem is obviously the `’` character in the source folder name. But why can't robocopy read that character?

Answer (score 2):

Using character set 1252 works on my windows 7 machine.

```
chcp 1252 

robocopy /MIR /E /DCOPY:T /s "c:\test\xupdate can't be deployed" "c:\test\out"
```

According to Notepad++ the .bat file is encoded:

> UTF-8 without BOM

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Aug 28 12:35:13 2015

   Source : c:\test\xupdate can't be deployed\
     Dest : c:\test\out\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    c:\test\xupdate can't be deployed\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Bytes :       245         0       245         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Fri Aug 28 12:35:13 2015
```

I used windows notepad to create the bat file.

Unfortunately I cannot recreate the above when creating a new .bat file with the same encoding. Robocopy fails regardless of encoding, the best I get is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Fri Aug 28 12:37:20 2015

   Source : c:\test\xupdate can't be deployed\
     Dest : c:\test\out\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2015/08/28 12:37:20 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory c:\test\xupd
ate can't be deployed\
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have to copy the original .bat files text into a new batch file to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar issue on a Win7 machine with file paths sometimes named with German ü and ö (u-Umlaut, o-Umlaut). chcp 1252 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making batch command file and save file with UTF-8 encoding, use `chcp 65001` at first line of batch file.
I'm from Czech Republic and have similiar issue.